# Index.js file error Warning: to load an ES module, set "type: "module" in the package.json file

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs, django

I am working on django-rest-framework site and keep getting and error with the index.js file. I've tried adding the .mjs file extension and changing package.json but nothing has fixed this error. VS code gives me the error of 'App is declared but its value is never read ts(6133). I run the python manage.py runserver and then the npm dev server command and I do not have any errors yet I am still not able to get the site to render some of the values in the console properly.

I am new to programming so please forgive my ignorance as I pretend to know something about what I am talking about here.

Here is my index.js file

```
import App from "./components/App";
```

This is the App.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HomePage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

package.json file

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a lint. It's telling you that in `index.js`, you have declared a variable (`App`), and not used it. Bad programming practice, so your linter (I think VSCode lints JS by default, or maybe you have installed a linter like ESLint) is telling you that. The 6133 number is the error number in the linter.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure why I kept getting those messages.

Comment: Sure. It's not much of a problem, just use `App` somewhere and it'll disappear. Linters help you write better code, that's all. If the answer helped, don't forget to upvote and accept. :)